# How to color specific vtkCells?

Tags: vtk

I have a 3D model loaded into a vtkActor and I need to be able to color specific vtkCells of this actor after selecting (clicking on those vtkCells). I know how to retrieve the selected cells from the vtkUnstructuredGrid but have no idea of how to set color to them. I've read a bit about vtkLookUpTables and think that might be it but I don't understand how it works, or if it really is what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vtkExtractCells to fetch all special cells and form a vtkDataObject, then create vtkDataSetMapper and vtkActor objects to color and shot it.